# JavaScript Hoisting

Tags: javascript

I was wondering, why the alert result is different after commenting out this line `function a() {}` ? What is the relationship between function a() and variable a?

**Snippet 1:**

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    //function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a); // 10
```

**Snippet 2:**

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `a` is getting redefined inside of `b` and removes the closure.

Comment: How did closure come into picture? PS: I didnt downvote

Comment: `a` is being closed around in `b` in the first example.

Comment: No, in the first example, `a` is being searched in the local scope first. It isn't found. So, enclosing scope is searched (there isn't any), finally global scope is searched and we find a match.